# PyParsing - match string followed by substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm trying to use PyParsing to parse some automatically generated SQL Server scripts. I can't get the parser to stop parsing at the `GO` keyword.

```
from pyparsing import *

test = '''
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
'''

working = Literal("SET") + Word(printables) * 2
not_working = Literal("SET") + OneOrMore(Word(printables) + ~Literal("GO"))

print('Working')
for result, start, end in working.scanString(test):
    print( "Found {0} at [{1}:{2}]".format(result, start, end))

print('\nNot working')
for result, start, end in not_working.scanString(test):
    print( "Found {0} at [{1}:{2}]".format(result, start, end))
```

The output is as follows:

```
"Working"
Found ['SET', 'ANSI_NULLS', 'ON'] at [1:18]
Found ['SET', 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER', 'ON'] at [22:46]

"Not working -- missing the ON keyword"
Found ['SET', 'ANSI_NULLS'] at [1:15]
Found ['SET', 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'] at [22:43]
```

For some reason, my "not working" example is not getting the `ON` keyword. How do I tell the parser to stop when it sees the `GO` keyword?

Comment: `OneOrMore(Word(printables), stopOn=Keyword("GO"))` should work (or was formerly done much as you thought, as `OneOrMore(~Keyword("GO") + Word(printables))` because the lookahead has to happen before matching, but I felt this was clunky looking, so added stopOn.  In general `Word(printables)` is often a red flag, it is too easy to get more than you intended. And for parsing keywords, use `Keyword`, not `Literal`. `Literal("GO")` would also match "GOOSE", "GOT", "GOING", etc. but `Keyword` match is restricted by word boundaries.

Comment: @PaulMcG thanks. Using `OneOrMore(Word(printables), stopOn=Keyword("GO"))` gets me closer, but now the final `"O"` matches that pattern as well.

Comment: You have to add something like `+ Keyword("GO").suppress()` to consume the "GO", since you told `OneOrMore` to stop before parsing it.